# Visual Studio Local IIS Web Server Project Url With Multiple Subdomains

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-7, subdomain

I would like to try testing virtual hosting of an ASP.Net MVC website on my local machine.  In Visual Studio in the **Web** tab of the properties file for the MVC project, I selected **Use Local IIS Web Server**.  By "virtual hosting", what I really mean is that I'm trying to make sure that pages load correctly for urls of the form http://sub-domain-i.my-domain.com/MyMvcProject/Controller/Action, where I'm hoping to test multiple subdomains in place of sub-domain-i.  In production, everything will be running under a single IP address on one server.  I also hope to test https for urls of this form using a wildcard ssl certificate, but currently I'm having trouble configuring Visual Studio to just test regular http.  Prior to worrying about sub-domains, the **Project Url** field in the **Web** tab of the properties folder for my MVC project said "http://localhost/MyMvcProject", and everything worked fine.  However, after changing this to "http://sub-domain-1.my-domain.com/MyMvcProject" and then adding the following line into my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file,

```
127.0.0.1    sub-domain-1.my-domain.com
```

Visual Studio produces the error "Unable to create the virtual directory.  http://sub-domain-1.my-domain.com/MyMvcProject".  Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

**Edit:**  I've just discovered that if I select **Use Custom Web Server** instead of **Use Local IIS Web server**, it works and I don't get the popup error from Visual Studio.  I'm still not sure why this solution works, though, or what I was doing wrong by selecting **Use Custom Web Server**...

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I hope it helps somebody.

You need to create the binding in the IIS website prior to add it to the project url of the project. That binding must be like

http | sub-domain-1.my-domain.com | 80 | * or 127.0.0.1

[How to create a binding](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding)